# PDO where clause and Limit can not work at a time

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

```
  function manage_user($startFrom = 0, $itemPerPage = 5)
    {
        $_userData = array();
        $this->db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `user_info` LIMIT ?, ? WHERE `user_info`.`status` = ? ");
        $query->execute(array($startFrom,$itemPerPage,'active')) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        $result = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $_userData[] = $row;
        }
        return $_userData;
    }
```

If use only limit then it's work fine.When use where clause it gets error. 
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object 
on **$query->execute()** line

Comment: Limit follows the where in normal syntax. (SELECT, FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY, LIMIT)  Move the limit so it's after the where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misplaced `LIMIT` and `WHERE` clause all together. `WHERE` should come before `LIMIT` clause like below. Moreover, a `LIMIT` clause without `ORDER BY` makes very little sense.

```
WHERE `user_info`.`status` = ? LIMIT ?, ?
```